# Nodejs and TypeError method 'trim' undefined when processing data from streaming

Tags: node.js

i have data below from streaming:

```
'ID|20120206|080500|0000001|0|1|record1|END'
'ID|20120206|080500|0000002|0|1|record2|END'
'ID|20120206|080500|0000003|0|1|record3|END'
```

and i want to process the streaming data line by line using nodejs code below:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = 'localhost',
    PORT = 9010,
    lastSeqNo = 0;

var client = new net.Socket();
client.setEncoding('ascii');

client.connect(PORT, HOST, function () {
    console.log('Connected to: %s : %d', HOST, PORT);
});

client.on('close', function (hadError) {
    console.log(hadError);
});

client.on('error', function (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
});

var i = 1;
var Line = function (rows, data) {
    this.SeqNo = parseFloat(rows[3].trim());
    this.Date = rows[1].trim();
    this.Time = rows[2].trim();
    this.MsgType = parseInt(rows[4].trim(), 10);
    this.Data = data;
};

client.on('data', function (data) {
    var content = data.split('\r\n');
    content.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item.length > 0) {
            console.log(i, item);
            i++;

            var rows = item.split('|'),
                line = new Line(rows, data),
                seqNo = line.SeqNo,
                msgType = line.MsgType;

            console.log('seqno:', seqNo);
        }
    });
});
```

after a few data line process, i got some error like below:

```
D:\test node\app.js:33
    this.SeqNo = parseFloat(rows[3].trim());
                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'trim' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (D:\test node\app.js:33:37)
    at D:\test node\app.js:48:24
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\test node\app.js:42:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:362:31)
```

could you help me what's wrong with my code above?

thank you. greeting from indonesia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` event does not guarantee that it sends full lines at once. Most likely the problem is that you actually got less data than what your code expects, thus `rows[3]` is undefined.

As you said yourself, you're streaming the data. When you listen for the `data` event, you might be getting just small bits of your data at once - not the full batch at once.

Comment: thank you @jani-hartikainen, it work ok now. below my code change after i read your reply:

i remove client.on 'data' from socket completely and replace it with this one.

var carrier = require('carrier');
var my_carrier = carrier.carry(client);
my_carrier.on('line',  function(line) {
    if (line.length > 0) {
        var rows = line.split('|'),
            aLine = new Line(rows, line),
            seqNo = aLine.SeqNo,
            msgType = aLine.MsgType;

        console.log('line:', line);
    }
});